# Topology One point Compactification and Metrizability

Tags: general-topology

Let X be an infinite set with the discrete topology. I am having trouble showing that the one-point compactification of X is metrizable if and only if X is countable.

Comment: What facts do you know about metrizability?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Every metrizable space is first countable.